# How can I completely uninstall jupyter nbextension?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have installed jupyter nbextension, and now I'm getting some errors. I've tried uninstalling it and using Disabled. Every time that I try to run Jupyter Notebook I'm getting this:

```
[I 09:49:05.617 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[W 09:49:05.643 NotebookApp] Error loading server extension jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1615, in init_server_extensions
mod = importlib.import_module(modulename)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_nbextensions_configurator'
[I 09:49:05.771 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from D:\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\jupyterlab
[I 09:49:05.771 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is D:\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 09:49:05.779 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\lauta
[I 09:49:05.779 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 09:49:05.779 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8889/? 
token=30e5b2769aadba944130bef16e08bd510b957b56c1e00442
[I 09:49:05.779 NotebookApp] or http://127.0.0.1:8889/? 
token=30e5b2769aadba944130bef16e08bd510b957b56c1e00442
[I 09:49:05.779 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to 
skip confirmation).
[C 09:49:05.919 NotebookApp] 

To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
......................................... (I erased this part)
[W 09:49:08.495 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main.js? 
v=20191029094904 (::1) 33.48ms referer=http://localhost:8889/tree
```

I can still use the notebooks. But I tried everything, even installing Anaconda again (with the clean statement). Any help? Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you using? Is this installed with pip?

Comment: Windows. And, yes. It was installed with pip.